# Record microphone and sound from application but only play application sound to headphones

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, microphone, jack

For my podcast I want to record my voice and music coming from an application but not hear my own voice in my headphones. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhseK.png)

I managed to create a virtual audio sink and merge the two audio signals to audacity. However, I struggle with connecting one input to two outputs (one for audacity, one for my headphones).  [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJO3S.png)

I fiddled around with Jack but couldn't find the correct tutorial to do what I want.

Basically I want something like [Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) in Ubuntu since I'm switching from Windows.